# Ensuring order of commands in Python

Tags: python, concurrency, jar

I have a .jar file that I'm running with arguments via `Popen`. This server takes about 4 seconds to start up and then dumps out "Server Started" on the terminal and then runs until the user quits the terminal. However, the `print` and `webbrowser.open` execute immediately because of `Popen` and if I use `call`, they never run at all. Is there a way to ensure that the `print` and `webbrowser` don't run until after the server is started other than using `wait`? Maybe grep for server started?

```
from subprocess import Popen
import glob 
import sys
import webbrowser

reasoner = glob.glob("reasoner*.jar")

reasoner = reasoner.pop()

port = str(input("Enter connection port: "))
space = ""
portArg = ("-p", port)
portArg = space.join(portArg)

print "Navigate to the Reasoner at http://locahost:" + port

reasoner_process = Popen(["java", "-jar", reasoner, "-i", "0.0.0.0", portArg, "--dbconnect", "jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost//tmp/UXDemo;user=sa;password=admin"])

# I want the following to execute after the .jar process above

print "Opening http://locahost:" + port + "..."
webbrowser.open("http://locahost:" + port)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking to do is a very simple, special version of interacting with a CLI app. So, you have two options.

First, you can use a library like [`pexpect`](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) that's designed to handle driving almost any CLI application. It may be overkill, and there is a bit of a learning curve, but once you get the basics down this will make your problem trivial: you launch the JAR, block expecting "Server Started", then close.

Alternatively, you can do this manually with the `Popen` pipes. In general this has a lot of problems, but when you know there's going to exactly one output that fits easily into 128 bytes and you don't want to do anything but block on that output and then close the pipe, none of those problems comes up. So:

```
reasoner_process = Popen(args, stdout=PIPE)
line = reasoner_process.stdout.readline()
if line.strip() != 'Server Started':
    # error handling

# Any code that you want to do while the server is running goes here

reasoner_process.stdout.close()
reasoner_process.kill()
reasoner_process.wait()
```

But first make sure you actually have to kill it; often closing the pipe is sufficient, in which case you can and should leave out the `kill()`, in which case you can also check the exit code and raise if it's not 0.

Also, you probably want a `with contextlib.closing(…)` or whatever's appropriate, or just a `try`/`finally` to make sure you can raise an exception for error handling and not leak the child. (Python 3.2+ makes this a lot simpler, because it guarantees that both the pipes and the `Popen` itself are usable as context managers.)

Finally, I was assuming that "runs until the user quits the terminal" means you want to wait for it to start, then leave it running while you do other stuff, then kill it. If your workflow is different, you obviously need to change the order in which you do things.